# I have some lists, I have merge them but how can I the value in descending order and put it as STD?

Tags: python, standards

My lists are shown:

```
['river: 0.3']
['spread: 0.04']
['idaho: 0.5']
```

I want to merge them together first then rank by the value in descending order and put it as standard output. Finally print a sentence, for example the highest value is 0.711, it will print:

```
"the largest value is idaho"
```

Here is my attempt but I failed when I wanna rank it:

```
u = ['river: 0.3']
v = ['spread: 0.04']
s = ['idaho: 0.5']
mergelist = u + v + s
ranklist = sorted(mergelist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for i in ranklist:
    print(' '.join(list(map(str, i))))
print("the largest value is" + ' ' + ranklist[0])
```

The desired standard output is:

```
idaho 0.5
river 0.3
spread 0.04
the largest value is idaho
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach

```
u = ['river: 0.3']
v = ['spread: 0.04']
s = ['idaho: 0.5']
mergelist = u + v + s

import operator

d = {}
for i in mergelist:
    val = i.split(":")
    d[val[0].strip()] = float(val[1].strip())

print("the largest value is {}".format(max(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
the largest value is Idaho
```

- split string by `:`
- Form  dict from split values.
- Use operator to get max value from your dict.

*As requested in comments*

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(k, v)
```

**Output:**

```
idaho 0.5
river 0.3
spread 0.04
```

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply. May I ask how can I get all the value display as standard output? Any mistake of my code?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Do you mean `print(d)`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I would like to print the all the values in standard output in descending order as well.

Comment: Updated snippet. Please check.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. the operator module is so good, I will go and learn it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

First of all

```
['river: 0.3']
['spread: 0.04']
['idaho: 0.5']
```

There are not pairs(i.e. not in the form of (x, y)).

What you need is something like this:

```
u = ['river', 0.3]
v = ['spread', 0.04]
s = ['idaho', 0.5]
```

and now we can't merge these with the plus(+) operation but rather

```
mergelist = [u, v, s]
```

and then

```
ranklist = sorted(mergelist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for i in ranklist:
    print(' '.join(list(map(str, i))))
print("the largest value is" + ' ' + str(ranklist[0][0]))
```

notice that I used ranklist[0][0] rather ranklist[0] because now it's a list of lists.

Comment: Hi do you modify the list to desired output?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, I didn't understand this question :(
the output was like this, though:
idaho 0.5
river 0.3
spread 0.04
the largest value is idaho

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the numeric values are still inside strings (which are inside a one element list for some reason). I suggest that you split the strings by `':'` and use a dictionary as your merging-datastructure as opposed to a list.

```
>>> u = ['river: 0.3']
>>> v = ['spread: 0.04']
>>> s = ['idaho: 0.5']
>>> 
>>> d = {}
>>> for item, in (u, v, s):
...     key, value = item.split(':')
...     d[key] = float(value)
... 
>>> d
{'spread': 0.04, 'river': 0.3, 'idaho': 0.5}
```

Note that `item,` unpacks a list of length 1.

Of course, if you hardcoded `u`, `v` and `s` you might as well just type 
`d = {'river': 0.3, 'spread': 0.04, 'idaho': 0.5}` in.

Now you have a nice, clean dictionary for easy lookup operations.

```
>>> d['river']
0.3
```

You can now either sort the dict's `items` by value in descending order ...

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
[('idaho', 0.5), ('river', 0.3), ('spread', 0.04)]
```

... or use the `max` builtin if you just need the (key, value) pair with the maximum value.

```
>>> max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
('idaho', 0.5)
>>>
>>> _, max_value = max(d.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
>>> max_value
0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the name and the float to a new dictionary the name as the key the float as the value then get the key that has the largest value:

```
rank = {}
u = ['river: 0.3']
v = ['spread: 0.04']
s = ['idaho: 0.5']
for i in u+v+s:
   rank[i.split(': ')[0]] = float(i.split(': ')[-1])
print("the largest value is {[0]}".format([i for i in rank.keys() if rank[i] == max(rank.values())]))
```

Output:

```
the largest value is idaho
```